# Java - Assigning variable in ternary operator - unexpected type error

Tags: java, variable-assignment, conditional-operator

I'm relatively new to coding and Java. I'm trying to work on using the ternary operator in place of some of my "if" statements.
When I code the below as an if/else, it works fine, but when I run it as is I get

```
unexpected type
required: variable
found:    value line:3
```

Can you not assign value via ternary, or am I doing it wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
  int front;
  nums.length>4 ? front = 4 : front = nums.length;
```

Comment: Did you mean `front = nums.length>4 ? 4 : nums.length;`?

Comment: Can you write down what you try to express? Or maybe give a classic if/else

Comment: @Amongalen Thank you! That is indeed what I intended, but had misunderstood the logic. I'll have to digest this syntax for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java the ternary operator is an "assignemnt" one, this means that the result of the operation "always" must be assigned to a variable.
The destination variable goes at left (as usual) of the symbol "=", whilst the operator goes at right.
As you said, it just works as an if/else. The structure is this one:

```
<destination_variable> = <condition> ? <value_if_cond_true> : <value_else>
```

So, in your specific case, the ternary operator will be written as follow:

```
int front = nums.length > 4 ? 4 : nums.length;
```

Comment: it can also be used as a return statement

Comment: what confuses me a bit is `return memo[begin] = res == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? res : res + 1;` as here https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-rounds-to-complete-all-tasks/solutions/2996311/java-5-solutions/

Comment: @chocalaca in that case, bear in mind that the assignment is the first operation executed, so the value of `res` is stored into `memo[begin]`, which is the element at position `begin` of array `memo`. Then the variable 'memo[begin]' is checked against `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, if the condition is true, then 'return' statement returns `res` to the invoked, otherwise it will return `res+1`